# MySQL SELECT If Statement WHERE Condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I created a module for rendering overtime. In the module you will select your approving person and it will be maximum of 3 persons.

The scenario is that I will display all approved overtimes if `manager1_date` is not `NULL`, `manager2_date` is not `NULL` and `manager3_date` is not `NULL`. But as i said, it can be only 1,2 or 3 approving person. what if i applied then i have only 2 approving persons, it should be if `manager1_date` is not `NULL` and `manager2_date` is not `NULL`.

I tried this query:

```
Select * from table1 
where manager1_date is not null 
AND (manager2_date is not null or manager3_date is not null)
```

In PHP, it displays the record but the record has 3rd approving person which is `manager3_date` is `NULL`. it should not display the record until the approving persons are filled out.

Comment: So just append that AND to your query?

Comment: Could I ask what is the difference? What do you mean by //no selection?

Comment: i edited it now.. sorry for confusion.

Comment: Is there a reason you're SHOUTING your question here? Apparently your CAPS lock is not stuck. Do you think typing your question IN ALL CAPS will get you an answer more quickly? (The answer to that is no, BTW.)

Comment: Did the answers below help you out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that all three managers must approve.  If so your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE manager1_date IS NOT null 
AND manager2_date IS NOT null 
AND manager3_date IS NOT null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you need to see when all three manager dates are not null, get rid of the "or".

```
Select * 
from   table1 
where  manager1_date is not null 
       AND manager2_date is not null 
       AND manager3_date is not null
```